# Are the modulations QPSK, 16QAM and 64QAM analog or numeric?

Tags: modulation

In the **LTE** networks, the modulations that are used by the base stations are **QPSK**, **16QAM** and **64QAM** according to the **SNR**.

Are the modulations QPSK, 16QAM and 64QAM analog or numeric?

I need to know because I am working in the cellular field (but as a developer).

Thank you in advance!

Bob the builder

Answer (score 0):

By "numeric", I assume you mean digital. Yes, LTE uses digital modulation, not analog. LTE is an OFDM format, and quite a lot of digital processing is done before the signal is converted to analog and transmitted. The processing includes modulation of multiple sub-carriers, inverse FFT, adding a cyclic prefix, windowing the edges of the symbols. All that is done digitally.